How do I avoid flash of an unnecessary component for 1 second after fetching data in React?

As you can see on the image, after fetching data and displaying it on the screen, orange button appears (in the center) for 1 second and then dissappears.
Code for component:
const Home: FC = () => {
    const { pizzas, loading, error, count } = useAppSelector(
        (state) => state.pizzas
    )
    const { categoryID, searchValue, currentPage, sortNameObj } =
        useAppSelector((state) => state.filter)
    const dispatch = useAppDispatch()

    const handleChangeCategory = useCallback((index: number) => {
        dispatch(setCategoryID(index))
        dispatch(setCurrentPage(1))
    }, [])

    const handleChangePage = (page: number) => {
        dispatch(setCurrentPage(page))
    }

    const pizzaList = pizzas?.map((item) => {
        const pizzaImg = pizzaImagesMiddle[item.title]

        return <PizzaCard key={item.id} item={item} pizzaImg={pizzaImg} />
    })

    const skeletons = [...new Array(4)].map((_, index) => (
        <PizzaSkeleton key={index} />
    ))

    const loadedPizzas = loading ? skeletons : pizzaList

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(fetchPizzas())
    }, [categoryID, searchValue, sortNameObj, currentPage])

    if (error) {
        return <EmptyResult title='Произошла ошибка' />
    }

    if (!loading && (!pizzas || pizzas?.length === 0)) {
        return <EmptyResult title='Пиццы не найдены' />
    }

    return (
        <div className={styles.home__container}>
            <div className={styles.content__header}>
                <Categories
                    handleChangeCategory={handleChangeCategory}
                    value={categoryID}
                />
                <Sort sortNameObj={sortNameObj} />
            </div>
            <h2>Все пиццы</h2>
            <section className={styles.content__list}>{loadedPizzas}</section>
            <Pagination
                handleChangePage={handleChangePage}
                currentPage={currentPage}
                itemsLength={count}
            />
        </div>
    )
}

It is because cheking pizzas length in condition if (!loading && (!pizzas || pizzas?.length === 0)). Without check of empty length if (!loading && !pizzas) everything goes well. But I need to check if array is empty or not.
In default, pizzas length is empty (so I have empty array before fetching data)
Pizza slice:
const initialState: PizzasState = {
    pizzas: [],
    loading: false,
    error: null,
    count: 0
}

const pizzasSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'pizzas',
    initialState,
    reducers: {},
    extraReducers: (builder) => {
        builder.addCase(fetchPizzas.pending, (state) => {
            state.loading = true;
            state.pizzas = [];
            state.error = null;
            state.count = 0
        });
        builder.addCase(fetchPizzas.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
            state.pizzas = action.payload.items;
            state.error = null;
            state.count = action.payload.count;
            state.loading = false
        });
        builder.addCase(fetchPizzas.rejected, (state, action) => {
            state.pizzas = [];
            state.count = 0;
            if (action.payload) {
                state.error = action.payload.message
            } else {
                state.error = action.error.message
            };
            state.loading = false
        })
    }
})

Question: How to properly avoid flashing <EmptyResult/> for 1 second?

To help you better, can you share rest of the code. Want to see how the values loading, pizzas are set

It seems that there is a situation where loading is false but pizzas variable is not set correctly. It is not falsy anymore, but its length is not 0. And if that is the case, then you should have them in sync right.

@Tushar Shahi, updated

Issue
The EmptyResult component is currently displayed when loading is true and the pizzas state is falsey or empty. The pizzas state is initially empty and is also set to [] when the fetchPizzas action is pending.
Solution
If you only want to display EmptyResult once data has been loaded then select a different value from [] - "fetched data and empty" and [....] - "fetched data and populated" to differentiate the states and loading conditions. Using undefined or null are valid choices here to indicate that data hasn't been fetched/loaded yet, and is easy to check in the UI.
const initialState: PizzasState = {
  pizzas: undefined, // <-- initially undefined
  loading: false,
  error: null,
  count: 0,
};

const pizzasSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'pizzas',
  initialState,
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(fetchPizzas.pending, (state) => {
      state.loading = true;
      // state.pizzas = []; // <-- Don't update yet
      state.error = null;
      state.count = 0
    });
    builder.addCase(fetchPizzas.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      state.pizzas = action.payload.items; // <-- update to "loaded" value
      state.error = null;
      state.count = action.payload.count;
      state.loading = false;
    });
    builder.addCase(fetchPizzas.rejected, (state, action) => {
      state.pizzas = []; // <-- update to "loaded" value
      state.count = 0;
      state.error = action.payload
        ? action.payload.message
        : action.error.message;
      state.loading = false;
    });
  },
});

Update the UI to check for undefined/null loaded data.
const skeletons = [...new Array(4)].map((_, index) => (
  <PizzaSkeleton key={index} />
));

const Home: FC = () => {
  const { pizzas, loading, error, count } =
    useAppSelector((state) => state.pizzas);
  const { categoryID, searchValue, currentPage, sortNameObj } =
    useAppSelector((state) => state.filter);
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();

  const handleChangeCategory = useCallback((index: number) => {
    dispatch(setCategoryID(index));
    dispatch(setCurrentPage(1));
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchPizzas())
  }, [categoryID, searchValue, sortNameObj, currentPage])

  const handleChangePage = (page: number) => {
    dispatch(setCurrentPage(page));
  };

  if (error) {
    return <EmptyResult title='Произошла ошибка' />;
  }

  // Check if pizzas is a defined array and empty
  if (!loading && (Array.isArray(pizzas) && !pizzas.length)) {
    return <EmptyResult title='Пиццы не найдены' />;
  }

  return (
    <div className={styles.home__container}>
      <div className={styles.content__header}>
        <Categories
          handleChangeCategory={handleChangeCategory}
          value={categoryID}
        />
        <Sort sortNameObj={sortNameObj} />
      </div>
      <h2>Все пиццы</h2>
      <section className={styles.content__list}>
        {loading
          ? skeletons
          : pizzas?.map((item) => (
            <PizzaCard
              key={item.id}
              item={item}
              pizzaImg={pizzaImagesMiddle[item.title]}
            />
          ))
        }
      </section>
      <Pagination
        handleChangePage={handleChangePage}
        currentPage={currentPage}
        itemsLength={count}
      />
    </div>
  );
};


Let us continue this discussion in chat.

you can either place a setTimeout(() => dispatch(fetchPizzas()), 1000) on your useEffect or, if any of those functions are async, you can use a State to conditionally render the component or not. Where you are returning the component that you want to delay, make something like: return shouldRenderPizza ? (your actual pizza component) : 
now, on your useEffect make something like dispatch(fetchPizzas().then(result => setTimeout(() => setShouldRenderPizza(true), 1000)))
